# Alternative to subsearch to search more than million entries

Tags: splunk

Hi I have a sub search command which gives me the required results but is dead slow in doing so. I am having more than a million log entries that i need to search which is the reason why i am looking for an optimized solution. I have gone through answers asked for similar questions but not able to achieve what i need

I have a log which has transactions against an entry_id which always has a main entry and may or may not have subEntry

I want to find the count of version number for all the mainEntry log which has a subEntry

sample Query that i used

```
index=index_a [search index=index_a ENTRY_FIELD="subEntry"| fields Entry_ID] Entry_FIELD="mainEntry" | stats count by version
```

Sample data

```
Index=index_a
1) Entry_ID=abcd Entry_FIELD="mainEntry" version=1
Entry_ID=abcd ENTRY_FIELD="subEntry"
2)Entry_ID=1234 Entry_FIELD="mainEntry" version=1
3)Entry_ID=xyz Entry_FIELD="mainEntry" version=2
4)Entry_ID=lmnop Entry_FIELD="mainEntry" version=1
Entry_ID=lmnop ENTRY_FIELD="subEntry"
5)Entry_ID=ab123 Entry_FIELD="mainEntry" version=3
Entry_ID=ab123 ENTRY_FIELD="subEntry"
```

Please help in optimizing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not entirely clear what your sample data looks like.

Is it that events 1, 4 and 5 have the fields `Entry_ID`, `Entry_FIELD`, `version`, `Entry_ID`, `Entry_FIELD` ? That is, 2 occurances of `Entry_ID` and `Entry_FIELD`?

You can try something like the following, but I think you need to explain your data a bit better.

```
index=index_a Entry_FIELD="subEntry" OR Entry_FIELD="mainEntry" 
| stats dc(Entry_FIELD) as Entry_FIELD_Count by Entry_ID, version 
| where Entry_FIELD_Count==2 
| stats count by version
```

Comment: Simon, Thanks you. your understanding of the problem is correct and the query u have provided will also work except that version is there only for mainEntry and not there for subEntry 1) Entry_ID=abcd Entry_FIELD="mainEntry" version=1
Entry_ID=abcd ENTRY_FIELD="subEntry"